# File upload with user access for Joomla 1.5

Tags: file-upload, joomla, components, joomla1.5

We want to make it possible for clients to download and upload files from our website. They must be able to see only the file they uploaded. We would also like to have files for download but select the users allowed to download them. So each client has their own front end where they see what they can download or they can upload their own Files.

My question is:

**Is there a component for Joomla 1.5 available?**

Our website runs on Joomla! 1.5.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this componet for the file downloads and uploads via the frontend of the site
http://www.jdownloads.com/

You will then need a file tree that shows the files within that folder, however I'm not quite sure users can only see the file they have uploaded themselves.